# sql search for duplicates and verify the rest of data in 2 tables (same structure)

Tags: mysql, search, duplicates

I have just added some data to a database that 8 people have written at the same time.

This left me with 8 tables of same structure:

```
id; mobile-phone; address; register-number; bla bla bla
```

I would like to search for duplicates from these 8 persons, I think the `mobile-phone` would be best to search for.

For each duplicate `mobile-phone` it would be great if the rest of the row would be verified for exact duplicates. In case I find let's say the same `address` I would like this field zeroed in all but one of the 8 tables. If all fields in a row are zero, it can be deleted.

I have used this to search before, but it's not so great:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT `mobile-phone`
  FROM `t1`
  UNION ALL
  SELECT `mobile-phone`
  FROM `t2`
) `tx`
GROUP BY `mobile-phone`
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

So this is a dream come true, but anything close to this would help me.
Thanks.

EDIT 1

I had an ideea but I am not sure what is not working:

```
UPDATE `t2` set `address`=0 WHERE `t1`.`address`=`t2`.`address` AND `t1`.`mobile-phone`=`t2`.`mobile-phone`
```

and I got `#1054 - Unknown column 't1.address' in 'where clause'`

EDIT 2

Found something and tried to adapt:

```
declare x INTEGER;
SET x = 1;
WHILE x <= 200 DO
  UPDATE `t2` set `address`=0 WHERE `address`=
    (select `address` from `t1` where mobile-phone`=
      (select `mobile-phone` from `t2` where `id`=x))
  SET x = x + 1;
END WHILE;
```

Now I have this error `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax`.